# Server performance metric tools for LAMP

Tags: performance, monitoring, metrics

Any suggestions for tools to monitor page load times/errors and other performance metrics for a PHP application?

I am aware of the FireBug and YSlow tools, but this is for more server monitoring.

Answer (score 4):

There is the classic 'ab' (apachebench) program. More power comes from [JMmeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/). For server health, I recommend Munin, which can painlessly capture data from several systems and aggregate it on one page.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/), it's the default tool to monitor servers. You can write plugins to report just about any data.

Answer (score 1):

For profiling your code, there's [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler). Doing regression testing with [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/JoeDog/Siege) can also be quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [httperf](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/). It's a very flexible tool and if you want to test how your application and webserver can deal with various traffic loads you should definitely give it a go.